# UITexView: End editing when hitting Done while in lowercase, add new line while in uppercase

Tags: swift, uitextview

Currently, I'm able to add a new line with this

```
if text == "\n"
```

But both lowercase or uppercase mode always return `"\n"`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean to jump to a new line while you have shift pressed instead of done?

Comment: sr for the late response, what I want is jumping to a new line when tap on the return/done button while the shift (up arrow to uppercase) is being pressed. If the shift isn't pressed, just end editting

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to detect if the system keyboard is showing in uppercased or lowercased mode and change the behavior of your Done button accordingly.

From my knowledge there is no way to detect the current state of the keyboard or detect if a certain keyboard key is pressed in iOS.

You will have to add two separate buttons to do the two different actions (end editing and start a new line).

In a `UITextView`, the default behavior of the system keyboard return key is to start a new line, so you can make your Done button end editing only. This way you have both desired actions assigned to two different buttons (keyboard return and Done).